# Tkinter Frame within Frame

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to visually group checkbuttons for my users. The end goal would look something like this: (edited image, not actually created with Tkinter)

[visual example of goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWSes.png)

As you can see, I am trying to keep the checkbutton in order, with a little frame around a certain portion of the checkbuttons.

What I have actually achieved with Tkinter thus far doesn't keep the order of the checkboxes. The second Tkinter Frame appears below the first. It looks like this:

[frame fail!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REV3l.png)

```
import Tkinter as tk
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox


class NestedFrames(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, root):

        self.top_label = Label(root, text='               ')
        self.top_label.pack()

        frame1 = LabelFrame(root, text='', padx=45, pady=30)
        frame1.pack(padx=0, pady=0)
        check0 = Checkbutton(frame1, text='check button 1', onvalue=1, offvalue=0)
        check0.grid(sticky=W)
        check1 = Checkbutton(frame1, text='check button 2', onvalue=1, offvalue=0)
        check1.grid(sticky=W)

        # attempt at frame within frame
        frame2 = LabelFrame(root, text="", padx=35, pady=20)
        frame2.pack(padx=5, pady=5)

        check2 = Checkbutton(frame2, text='check button 3', onvalue=1, offvalue=0)
        check2.grid(sticky=W)
        check3 = Checkbutton(frame2, text='check button 4', onvalue=1, offvalue=0)
        check3.grid(sticky=W)
        check4 = Checkbutton(frame2, text='check button 5', onvalue=1, offvalue=0)
        check4.grid(sticky=W)
        check5 = Checkbutton(frame2, text='check button 6', onvalue=1, offvalue=0)
        check5.grid(sticky=W)

        # without second frame
        # space_A_label = Label(frame1, text=' ')
        # space_A_label.grid(sticky=W)
        # check2 = Checkbutton(frame1, text='check button 3', onvalue=1, offvalue=0)
        # check2.grid(sticky=W)
        # check3 = Checkbutton(frame1, text='check button 4', onvalue=1, offvalue=0)
        # check3.grid(sticky=W)
        # check4 = Checkbutton(frame1, text='check button 5', onvalue=1, offvalue=0)
        # check4.grid(sticky=W)
        # check5 = Checkbutton(frame1, text='check button 6', onvalue=1, offvalue=0)
        # check5.grid(sticky=W)
        # space_B_label = Label(frame1, text=' ')
        # space_B_label.grid(sticky=W)

        check6 = Checkbutton(frame1, text='check button 7', onvalue=1, offvalue=0)
        check6.grid(sticky=W)

        check7 = Checkbutton(frame1, text='check button 8', onvalue=1, offvalue=0)
        check7.grid(sticky=W)
        check8 = Checkbutton(frame1, text='check button 9', onvalue=1, offvalue=0)
        check8.grid(sticky=W)

        self.side_of_buttons_label = Label(root, text='         ')
        self.side_of_buttons_label.pack(side=RIGHT)
        self.run_button = Button(root, text='Run', command=self.btn_Run)
        self.run_button.pack(side=RIGHT)
        self.between_buttons_label = Label(root, text='  ')
        self.between_buttons_label.pack(side=RIGHT)
        self.exit_btn = Button(root, text='Exit', command=self.btn_exit_OnClickk)
        self.exit_btn.pack(side=RIGHT)

    def btn_exit_OnClickk(self):
        root.destroy()
        sys.exit()

    def btn_Run(self):
        tkMessageBox.showinfo("Run message", "clicked!")


root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Frame in Frame')
root.geometry('260x400')

app = NestedFrames(root)
root.mainloop()
```

How do I add in the second, inner frame in order to visually assist my users?

Comment: First of all, why are you inheriting from `tk.Frame` but not even calling the constructor? Also why don't you make 3 frames? 1st frame: labels 1, 2. 2nd frame labels: 3, 4, 5, 6. 3rd frame labels: 7, 8, 9

Comment: You need to actually put frame 2 into frame 1 by using `frame1` as the parent instead of `root`.

Comment: is there a particular reason you are using `Python2` (which is deprecated btw) and not `Python3`? also you should try avoiding use of global variables when using classes (such as `root` inside the `NestedFrames` class) not that it is bad or anything (at leas as far as I know it works and stuff but the point of classes is to kinda be containers of relevant code, idk, I just feel like it is not right using something directly from the global scope inside the classes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest following these rules:

- make all checkbuttons children of the same frame -- the one which surrounds all of the checkbuttons
- create three inner frames, two with an invisible border and one with a visible border. Keeping the borders the same size will help to get everything to line up
- use the `in_` parameter to place the checkbuttons in the appropriate inner frame.

It might look something like the following example. Even though the OP's code uses python2, this solution uses python3. The only difference is in the import of tkinter.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
cbframe = tk.Frame(root, bd=2, relief="groove")
cbframe.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=2, padx=20, pady=20)

innerframe1 = tk.Frame(cbframe, bd=2, relief="flat")
innerframe2 = tk.Frame(cbframe, bd=2, relief="groove")
innerframe3 = tk.Frame(cbframe, bd=2, relief="flat")

innerframe1.pack(side="top", padx=10, pady=(10,0))
innerframe2.pack(side="top", padx=10)
innerframe3.pack(side="top", padx=10, pady=(0, 10))

checkbuttons = []
vars = []
for i in range(10):
    var = tk.IntVar(value=0)
    cb = tk.Checkbutton(cbframe, variable=var, text=f"check button {i+1}", anchor="w")
    checkbuttons.append(cb)
    vars.append(var)

checkbuttons[0].pack(in_=innerframe1, side="top", ipadx=10)
checkbuttons[1].pack(in_=innerframe1, side="top", ipadx=10)
checkbuttons[2].pack(in_=innerframe2, side="top", ipadx=10)
checkbuttons[3].pack(in_=innerframe2, side="top", ipadx=10)
checkbuttons[4].pack(in_=innerframe2, side="top", ipadx=10)
checkbuttons[5].pack(in_=innerframe2, side="top", ipadx=10)
checkbuttons[6].pack(in_=innerframe3, side="top", ipadx=10)
checkbuttons[7].pack(in_=innerframe3, side="top", ipadx=10)
checkbuttons[8].pack(in_=innerframe3, side="top", ipadx=10)

root.mainloop()
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thank you! As the text for each checkbutton will not actually be numbered for the real project, and needs to be unique text for each, I am figuring out how to pull the text assignment out of your loop. But that's the general idea.

Comment: @lep: instead of iterating over a range of numbers, iterate over a list containing the text for each button.